# how to recognize an identifier inside a parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Hello I have a problem in the line

```
ON S.cid = P.cid
```

I get 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier. I don't really understand how to resolve it. I am new to SQL so any input about this particular problem would be of great help. Also this might not be the only problem with this code. So if anyone sees anything else that is strange please give me some input on that aswell.

```
SELECT S.cid, NLV(SUM(P.credits#),0) AS mathCred
FROM Students S
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT P.cid , P.credits#
FROM PassedCourses P
JOIN HasClass H
ON P.code = H.code AND H.name = 'mathematical')
ON S.cid = P.cid
GROUP BY S.cid;
```

Comment: You also seem to have 'NLV' instead of 'NVL'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an alias for the subquery:

```
SELECT S.cid, NLV(SUM(ph.credits#),0) AS mathCred
FROM Students S LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT P.cid , P.credits#
      FROM PassedCourses P JOIN
           HasClass H
           ON P.code = H.code AND H.name = 'mathematical'
     ) ph
     ON S.cid = ph.cid
GROUP BY S.cid;
```

The `p` is known in the subquery but not outside it.  Just give the subquery an alias and use that.

Comment: I have done that thanks however that is not the end of it. It seems that now i get an missing expression error in line 1

Comment: @Taga - that will be from the NLV/NVL typo.

Comment: Thanks that was clumsy of me!